# How to add one parameter to current url in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 links

```
 <li class="active">
  <a href="<%#CurrentSearchUrl%>"><span>Current search Page
 </span></a> 

  <li><a href="<%#CurrentSearchUrlParam%>"><span>Add param </span>
      </a>
```

in the Page_Load

```
    CurrentSearchUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    CurrentSearchUrlParam = Request.Url+"&discount=1";
```

param is added but url is not correct
my current url is

```
http://localhost:1067/search/default.aspx?q=test
```

I want to add one parameter, the desired result should be

```
http://localhost:1067/search/default.aspx?q=test&discount=1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are looking for [Query String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987952/how-to-properly-use-a-querystring-in-net-asp-c)

Comment: CurrentSearchUrlParam and CurrentSearchUrlDiscount are different. are you using correct parameter on page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many way to do that. For example :

Your HTML :

```
<li class="active">
  <a href="" runat="server" ID="Link1"><span>Current search Page
 </span></a> 

  <li><a href="" runat="server" ID="Link2"><span>Add param </span>
      </a>
```

In the Page_Load :

```
Link1.HRef = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
Link2.HRef = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()+"&discount=1";
```

Comment: what I did gives me same result as what you propose

Comment: What if there are other parameters in the url?

Comment: same question here what if there's a parameter in the url and i need to replace after doing so?

Answer (score 22):

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
var paramValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
paramValues.Add("param1", "value1");
paramValues.Add("param2", "value2");
uriBuilder.Query = paramValues.ToString();

Link1.HRef=uriBuilder.Uri;
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, I think, since it takes care of the case in which the original URL had no querystring parameters as well.

Answer (score 11):

Be careful of already existing parameters.
Here is a small modification of Victor' code:

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
var paramValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);

if(paramValues.Get("param1")!=null) paramValues.Remove("param1");
paramValues.Add("param1", "value1");
paramValues.Add("param2", "value2");
uriBuilder.Query = paramValues.ToString();

Link1.HRef=uriBuilder.Uri;
```

Comment: thank you but why the page won't open up, it just change the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

A small modification to the previous modification... As paramValues is a NameValueCollection you can access them with the this[] parameters.

```
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    var paramValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);

    paramValues["param1"] = "value1";
    paramValues["param2"] = "value2";
    uriBuilder.Query = paramValues.ToString();

    Link1.HRef=uriBuilder.Uri;
```